# CSS on Magento staging website not updating

Tags: css, magento, varnish, page-caching

Since last tuesday, out of the blue the css on our Magento staging website won't update after I've saved changes. The staging website has been working well for over a year. On the live Magento website the css is updating fine.

Last friday **we installed a Varnish pagecache extension by Phoenix on the live website**. Maybe that has something to do with it. The things I've tried to do to solve the problem:

- refreshing and clearing all of magento caches, including js/css.
- deleting all files in media/css folder.
- deleting folders from var/cache.
- disable merged css file. This works once. Same goes for enableing it again.
- renaming css files. This works once.
- renaming template, skin & layout package. This worked once.
- clearing browser cache.

Is anyone firmilliar with this problem? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Check http headers for that CSS file. If you find Age > 0 it means that the file is cached in Varnish

Comment: I bet the CSS file is cached in varnish. You could try restarting varnish to clear its cache and then see if the updated css file shows up.